# SQL Query to return difference and separate query to return matches between two tables

Tags: sql

I need to compare two table with only one column.
The query should return matches and a separate query should return differences.

I created the below query however i still cannot get the information i require.

Both tables only have a column called IDNumber 
Schema information for the columns is exactly the same
Data Type is Nvarchar 50

```
select * from EPE_Data_Cycle_77
Where [IDNumber] In ( select [IDNumber]
from  [EPE_Data_Cycle_76])
```

The tables contains over 2 millions rows 
Schema Information

```
TABLE_CATALOG   TABLE_SCHEMA    TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME ORDINAL_POSITION    COLUMN_DEFAULT  IS_NULLABLE DATA_TYPE   CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH    CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH  NUMERIC_PRECISION   NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX NUMERIC_SCALE   DATETIME_PRECISION  CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG   CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA    CHARACTER_SET_NAME  COLLATION_CATALOG   COLLATION_SCHEMA    COLLATION_NAME  DOMAIN_CATALOG  DOMAIN_SCHEMA   DOMAIN_NAME
XRG_P_SmartLife_Aug_2018    dbo EPE_Data_Cycle_76   IDNumber    1   NULL    YES nvarchar    50  100 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    UNICODE NULL    NULL    Latin1_General_CI_AI    NULL    NULL    NULL
XRG_P_SmartLife_Aug_2018    dbo EPE_Data_Cycle_77   IDNumber    1   NULL    YES nvarchar    50  100 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    UNICODE NULL    NULL    Latin1_General_CI_AI    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And what is the issue with your query?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this and not have any duplicates returned, you would need to use distinct on combined tables. This is how I accomplished the task:

```
DECLARE @temp1 TABLE ( IDNumber NVARCHAR(MAX) )
DECLARE @temp2 TABLE ( IDNumber NVARCHAR(MAX) )

INSERT INTO @temp1 VALUES ('1'),('2'),('22'),('33')
INSERT INTO @temp2 VALUES ('3'),('2'),('77'),('33')


SELECT DISTINCT IDNumber FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM @temp1
    WHERE IDNumber IN (SELECT IDNumber FROM @temp2)
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM @temp2
    WHERE IDNumber IN (SELECT IDNumber FROM @temp1)
) matches

SELECT DISTINCT IDNumber FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM @temp1
    WHERE IDNumber NOT IN (SELECT IDNumber FROM @temp2)
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM @temp2
    WHERE IDNumber NOT IN (SELECT IDNumber FROM @temp1)
) differences
```

OUTPUT:

```
matches table:
2
33

differences table:
1
22
3
77
```